# docker couchdb data volume doesn't save to local filesystem

Tags: docker

Docker newbie here...

I am trying to persist docker run couch db on my local filesystem but when I run the command I don't see the db files being saved. I tried researching but I seem to be doing everything right.

```
jubin@jubin-VirtualBox:~$ docker run -d -p 5984:5984 -v /home/jubin/data:/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb --name couchdb klaemo/couchdb
5e0d15b933d6344d3c6a28c26e1f2f59dba796697d47ff21b2c0971837c17e54
jubin@jubin-VirtualBox:~$ curl -X PUT http://172.17.0.2:5984/db
{"ok":true}
jubin@jubin-VirtualBox:~$ ls -ltr /home/jubin/data/
total 0
```

on inspect it seems to be correctly configured.

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "ea1ab54976ef583e2ca1222b4aeea420c657d48cb0987a0467a737ee3f68df02",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ea1ab54976ef583e2ca1222b4aeea420c657d48cb0987a0467a737ee3f68df02/_data",
            "Destination": "/opt/couchdb/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/jubin/data",
            "Destination": "/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: can you provide the dockerfile and compose file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the image documentation, the CouchDB data are stored in `/opt/couchdb/data` and not in `/usr/local/var/lib/couchdb` in the latest version of the image (`2.0.0/latest`).

You can also confirm this by doing `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` and then locating the CouchDB data inside the container.